# Display the Result of RemoteAttribute in MVC 3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a ViewModel setup to use RemoteValidation using the `RemoteAttribute`. It works fine.

### EDIT

> Updated it a bit to show some fixed code.
>
> I want to point out that this is not my actual "Register" code. This is testing it so I can use it in other situations. I'm not having users register using flat names!

Here are the libraries I am referencing, and how I am referencing them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Here is how I am wiring the RemoteAttribute.

```
public class UserRegistrationModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[a-zA-Z\p{L} \.'\-]{3,48})$", ErrorMessage = "This name contains invalid characters. Names must be between 3 and 48 characters, contain only standard unicode symbols, and may not contain any punctuation other than the ['] and [-] symbols.")]
    [Remote("ValidateUserName", "Membership", ErrorMessage = "{0} is invalid.")]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then here is the actual controller behavior.

```
    public ActionResult ValidateUserName(string name)
    {
        // perform logic

        if (true)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have inspected my HTML, and this functions as I want. But I don't understand what to do from there. How can I display that information to the user? It just stores it in the html

`data-val-remote="* is invalid"`

I have watched, and I notice that even when the `RemoteAttribute` returns false, the html changes from

`value` to `value class="valid"`, but in my other model validations, this changes to `class="input-validation-error"'.

So does anyone have any clues on how to draw the remote message back? Or is there really nothing I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
public class UserRegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[a-zA-Z\p{L} \.'\-]{3,48})$", ErrorMessage = "This name contains invalid characters. Names must be between 3 and 48 characters, contain only standard unicode symbols, and may not contain any punctuation other than the ['] and [-] symbols.")]
    [Remote("ValidateUniqueName", "Home")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new UserRegistrationViewModel());
    }

    public ActionResult ValidateUniqueName(string Name)
    {
        if (NameIsValid(Name)) 
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(string.Format("{0} is invalid", Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.UserRegistrationViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

You may also find the [following blog post](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2010/12/07/remote-validation-asp-net-mvc3.aspx) useful.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I am doing... but still no dice. The error message never displays. Even changing the error result to `Json(false)` doesn't cause it to throw up the validation error.

Comment: Yes. I have those files, I believe. Hold on, let me post an update to my own question so you can verify if I am doing something super-wrong.

Comment: Alright, I have made some updates to my code to better reflect how it has evolved since I originally posted my question. I have unfortunately read the blog post you linked, it is where I began and got the initial information from to start making this happen. I have also read the MSDN post on remote validation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: @Stacey, I have modified my initial answer. After testing, it seems that you cannot specify a dynamic error message with the RemoteAttribute. The `{0}` won't be replaced with the value entered by the user but with the name of the property which I suppose is not what you want. So in the controller action you could return a dynamic string that contains the error message to be shown to the user. So if the action returns true, no message will be shown, if it returns false it will show the error message of the RemoteAttribute and if you return a string it will show this string as error message.

Comment: Even still, it isn't functioning for some reason... If you'll permit me a few moments to try constructing a sandbox project that has nothing else in it, I'd like to make sure none of my other code is interfering, and then I will post another comment.

Comment: @Stacey, OK, that's what I did when I posted my answer. Normally this should work.

Comment: Still no dice. It _does stop_ post back. I can place a debug point, and the validation _is working_. But it won't _show the error_. For some reason, there is nothing flagging it to actually display the error on the View.

Comment: @Stacey, did you include it inside a form (Html.BeginForm)? The validation message will be shown when you try to submit the form.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I've put inside of the BeginForm block.

Comment: @Stacey, could you send me your sample project by email so that I can take a look at? The one you've created from scratch containing only the minimum information.

Comment: *Problem Identified*. The problem is jQuery 1.5.1. I'm not sure _why_, but when I switch to the 1.4+ included in the MVC template, it works, but when I use the newest jQuery, it doesn't. Maybe I need new Validation libraries too?

Comment: @Stacey, yes, you probably need a new version of jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive which are compatible with jquery 1.5.1. For the first you could probably find at the jquery.validate web site, for the second I am afraid you will have to modify the existing one because this file is supplied by Microsoft.

Comment: Lovely... No idea where to even begin with fixing that one.

Comment: Further digging led me to the creator of jquery validation plugin, http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ who states clearly on his website that the most syndicated version is not 1.5.X compatible, and using the version on his GitHub, I was able to make this work.

Comment: I will award the bounty points as soon as StackOverflow lets me. It still says I have to wait 1 hour. Sorry Darin. You're always there for me when I'm stupid. :P

Comment: @Stacey, no worries, always happy if I could help. Also stupid is not the one who asks about something, it's the one who thinks he knows and doesn't ask. So at the contrary, with this question you might help other people having the same problem and you have contributed to the community with it.

Comment: I live in a small town where we don't have a big market for developers, I do not have a lot of personal peers that I can ever ask questions to or ping ideas off of - Stackoverflow is literally some of the only _actual_ developer interaction I am able to get. Personally I think this is the best website on the entire internet. I know a lot of my questions are pretty plain, and I've even had people email me and say that they are outright bad, but I agree with you - I may not be the only developer with an issue.

Comment: On that note, in back-necro reference to my topic about 'What the hell Dependency Injection really is', it's seemed pretty popular, so I'm actually going to be setting up a website in the near future for _primer_ level coding references. A sort of hub, not on the scale of stackoverflow, but more like "TechNet for Dummies" where programmers can document actual techniques and practices in very, very, very elementary level format for aspiring, beginner programmers.