# MVC 3 remote validate field has a complex name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an input

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Buyer.Email, new { @maxlength = "100" })
```

I want to validate it with remote attribute

```
[Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "Validation")]        
public string Email { get; set; }
```

In validation controller I have an action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IsUserNameAvailable(string Email)
```

But, of course I get a null value in Email parameter. What parameter name should I pass to IsUserNameAvailable method?

Update: Just looked the request, that is sent to remote validation action:
http://myhost/Validation/IsUserNameAvailable?Buyer.Email=test@test.test
Parameter name is Buyer.Email, how should I pass it to function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of HttpPost use HttpGet. You are not posting anything. You are retrieving the result. Second make sure that when you return the result from IsUserNameAvailable that you specify that you allow JSON get.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IsUserNameAvailable(string Email)
{
    // Do something
    if (your_email_check_returns_true)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I suppose you didn't catch the idea of issue. I say, that when my parameter is called Email - it is null, because it's name should correspond the name of the field it validates. I removed [HttpPost] at all and still getting Email parameter as null.

Comment: Have a look at this SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121160/display-the-result-of-remoteattribute-in-mvc-3-0. You are on the right track. Just one question, what is the idea behind @maxlength? Have you tried using StringLength attribute?

Comment: @maxlength - is just adding of html attribute, that limits length of the string on the page

Comment: and sorry, still have no idea how to name the parameter of validator. For instance, if I had a @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email) I would name parameter "Email". But what name should I give to parameter when I have m => m.Buyer.Email?

Comment: Have a look at the generated page. I'll take my chance and say that it is something like Buyer_Email.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot name the string property as "Buyer.email", that should work... What if you expect a "Buyer" view model in your controller and let ModelBinder to populate the Buyer email property?

Comment: This, of course, will help. But I wanted to extent model with some fields except the fields from Buyer entity. Right now I'm reading the value directly from querystring and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the signature of your action to include a bind prefix:

```
public JsonResult IsUserNameAvailable([Bind (Prefix="Buyer.") ] string Email)
```